# gdal_grid.exe has stopped working. Why?

Tags: python, grid, access-violation, gdal, elevation

I have a number og geojson files containing surfaces and I need to make a DEM for each. This means that for each surface, I want a geotiff, where each pixel is the height of the surface.

I tried using gdal_grid:

```
gdal_grid -a linear:radius=0 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -outsize 15457 27059 surface.geojson DEM.tif
```

According to the documentation `linear:radius=0` should cause it to use a Delaunay triangulation between the points to find the height in each pixel.

This works for a lot of my files, but for some of them gdal_grid crashes and shows a "gdal_grid.exe has stopped working"-window. According to the windows debugger it is an Access Violation Exception. I just don't understand why.

I cannot find a pattern in which files makes the program crash. It is not the biggest files or the smallest files, and they are all pretty simple 3d-polygons.

All geojson files are in UTM32 (Denmark), but it doesn't always work for WGS84 either.

I also tried the same in python, but with the same result:

```
raster = gdal.Grid(rasterName, featureJson, outputSRS = outputCrs, width = rasterWidth, height = rasterHeight, algorithm = 'linear:radius=0')
```

The exception isn't always thrown at the same time in the code, and sometimes one of the problem-files actually finishes to the end, but the DEM then has weird areas with zeros in the middle of the polygon.

Please help me find out why gdal_grid sometimes throws an **Access Violation Exception**.